# Hololens 1 with Unity 2019.2 Interactable events are not called

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Trying to get e.g. Button Events from the Interactable script to run. Everything works fine in the Editor (Unity 2019.2) but deployed on the Hololens 1 or the Simulator the Buttons is changing its state but none of the linked click events is called.

I also tried it with a fresh project and a button hiding a cube on tap after the docs:
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Button.html

I am using MixedRealityToolkit 2.0 and the lates Unity MR packaes 3.0.5

Comment: did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: Yes but there is no error, it just not calling the linked events.

Comment: Could you please share screenshots or code of how you are configuring your interactable?

Comment: I had "WSA Holographic remoting supported" check under build settings. That was causing the problems with the button events. Not sure why that is such an issue...